# How can I make a clickable link add items to a list?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a simple web interface that shows asset numbers for pieces of equipment in our company database. I have a clickable link next to the number that says `Deploy` and `Return`. What I would like to happen is when someone clicks `Deploy`, the asset number for that specific piece of equipment is added to a list (eventually for to a csv file for printing), along with its requisite model and serial numbers.

How can I make the clickable link execute a function that takes that specific asset number next to it, searches the database for its model and serial numbers and adds them to a list?

The idea is that I can click `Deploy` on a bunch of assets and have them on a deployment sheet that is suitable for printing. I'm new to Django, and I've been using a Mozilla tutorial for the skeleton of this site, but now I'm going off the reservation a little bit. Thanks!

**`models.py`**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse #Used to generate URLs by reversing the URL patterns
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import uuid
from datetime import date

class ModelInstance(models.Model):
    asset = models.CharField('Asset Number', max_length = 50, help_text = "Enter Weston or Government I.D. Tag Number")
    model = models.ForeignKey('Model', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True, help_text = "Leave blank if no model number exists")
    serial = models.CharField('Serial Number', max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True, help_text = "Leave blank if no serial number exists")
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True, help_text = "Enter current location or location after manufacturing")
    ownership = models.ForeignKey('Ownership', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True, help_text = "Enter current owner of equipment")
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    STATUS = (
        ('M', 'Maintenance'),  #being worked on, not available
        ('D', 'Deployed'),   #in the field
        ('A', 'Available'),   #ready to go
        ('R', 'Reserved'), #Being used for classified/other project but not deployed
        ('K', 'Broken'), #Broken
    )

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length = 1,
        choices = STATUS,
        blank = True,
        default = 'A',
        help_text = 'Equipment Availability',
    )

    note = models.TextField('Notes', max_length = 1000, null = True, blank = True)

    date_added = models.DateField("Date Added", default=date.today())

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Asset Number: {self.asset}..........Serial Number: {self.serial}..........Location: {self.location}..........Ownership: {self.ownership}'

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField('Equipment Type', max_length = 50, help_text = "Enter general category of equipment")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories" #default would have shown as "Categorys" on admin page

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
```

**category_list.html**:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div style="margin-left:20px; margin-top:20px">
      <h1>Model list</h1>
    </div>

  {% if category_list %}
    {% for category in category_list %}
        <ul><strong>{{ category }}</strong></ul>
            <ul>
              {% for model in category.model_set.all %}
                <a href="{{ model.get_absolute_url }}"> {{ model.model_number }}..............{{ model.description }} </a>
            <ul>    {% for copy in model.modelinstance_set.all %}
                    <li>{{ copy.asset }} <a href="">Deploy</a> <a href="">Return</a>
                    <p class="{% if copy.status == 'A' %}text-success{% elif copy.status == 'M' %}text-danger{% else %}text-warning{% endif %}">{{ copy.get_status_display }}</p>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
            </ul>

              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
        <p>There is no equipment in the database</p>
  {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('books/', views.BookListView.as_view(), name='books'),
    path('book/<int:pk>', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='book-detail'),
    path('models/', views.ModelListView.as_view(), name='models'),
    path('model/<int:pk>', views.ModelDetailView.as_view(), name='model-detail'),
    path('category/', views.CategoryListView.as_view(), name='categories'),
]

urlpatterns += [
    path('mybooks/', views.LoanedBooksByUserListView.as_view(), name='my-borrowed'),
]

urlpatterns += [
    path('book/<uuid:pk>/renew', views.renew_book_librarian, name="renew-book-librarian"),
]
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render #generates HTML fiels using a template and data
#from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Book, Author, BookInstance, Genre, Model, ModelInstance, Category, Ownership, Manufacturer, Location #imports model classes to access data in views
from django.views import generic

class BookListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book

class BookDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Book

class ModelListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Model

class ModelDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Model

class CategoryListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Category
```

Comment: This is a bit broad unfortunately. If you want it to happen via a link, you'll need to use Ajax - you need some JavaScript to send the data and Django views to update the db when called.